# I am building an Android app using Parse, but I am not able to create an object

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am new to Parse. I wanted to create a test object, I have used the following code for initializing it:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "W10AcPJEV80uy3ZXtRfLi06VNzvy680rtPm9N", "yIkBHQWdWdZljTpJENeDkfCtsvrCTGwgb5oYW");
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("foo", "bar");
testObject.saveInBackground();
```

But when I check the Data browser in the Parse dashboard, I see nothing. At the same time, I can see a request was made from my app. I have added the necessary permissions on the manifest as well.

Answer (score 5):

Check [**this**](http://www.michaelevans.org/blog/2013/08/14/tutorial-building-an-android-to-do-list-app-using-parse). Hopefully It will help u a lot.

**Parse Setup:**
In the onCreate method of your Activity, add the following (remember to replace APP_ID and CLIENT_ID with the keys you got from Parse earlier):

```
Parse.initialize(this, "APP_ID", "CLIENT_ID");
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

In addition to that initializer code, we’ll need to add get some permissions for our app. Add the following two permissions to your

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

initialization code:

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Task.class)
```

**creating object user as:**

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();    
user.setUsername(mUsernameField.getText().toString());    
user.setPassword(mPasswordField.getText().toString());    
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback(){
.....
....
}
```